# Set user defined environment variables for spring boot webapp deployed in apache tomcat container

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, environment-variables

I have a spring boot app hosted on AWS Ubuntu instance, deployed using WAR deployment from Jenkins, in Apache tomcat(8.5.14) container.
I have one environment variable defined in **application-test.properties** file as below-
`drehr.config.upload.image = /home/ubuntu/ehrFiles/`
(application-test.properties file is used because active profile is set to **test**)
My java code accesses this property using following syntax:-

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

@Value("${drehr.config.upload.image}")
private String imagePath;
```

But I am unable to get its value in `imagePath` variable, it is coming blank and the code is failing. Please provide some way to the solution for this.
Also tried changing the property value inside `apache-tomcat-x/webapps/drehrweb-0.0.1/WEB-INF/classes/application-test.properties`. Still doesn't work.
The strange thing is the same code works fine on development environment(using spring tool suite).

Comment: Does it work with the default property file? 
This can happen if class is not component

Comment: Are you setting the profile variable on the AWS instance? Are you using the 'test' profile on AWS or is there a separate profile?

Comment: Does your startup log print the active profiles? Is your target profile listed? I always see this reported in the log like: "The following profiles are active: default,version,TEST"

Comment: @KevinB yes I am using the test profile on AWS. And I can see the following reported in the log: **"The following profiles are active: test"**

Comment: What do you mean "coming back blank and code is failing". Does "blank" mean null or empty string. By "failing" are you getting an exception? An exception stack trace might help.

Comment: @KevinB "blank" I meant empty string. And in the java code, I am building the full path of file for upload by joining base path and fileName where `drehr.config.upload.image` is used as base path. Now, as the base path is coming "blank", code is throwing `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: I also have this issue. Did you ever resolve this?